# latex graph points tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I drawed a simple path in graph

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw,shape=circle]
\draw[xshift=-1cm] (-2,0) node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt,label=below:$x$](x){};
\draw[xshift=-1cm] (-1,0) node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt,label=below:$y$](y){};
\draw[xshift=-1cm] (0,0) node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt,label=below:$z$](z){};
\draw[xshift=-1cm] (1,0) node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt,label=below:$k$](k){};
\draw (x) -- (k);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

But I need to draw more 3 vertex on this path (between y and z)
[image]

I tried the
    \fill [dot] (x) circle (.3mm);
but it doesnot work. Can you help me plz?

Comment: Just FYI for the future: the end result of using `xshift` on _everything_ is that the shift has no effect on the appearance of the graphic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply use a a `dotted` line:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzstyle{every node}=[draw,shape=circle]
  \draw[xshift=-1cm] (-2,0) node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt,label=below:$x$](x){};
  \draw[xshift=-1cm] (-1,0) node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt,label=below:$y$](y){};
  \draw[xshift=-1cm] ( 0,0) node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt,label=below:$z$](z){};
  \draw[xshift=-1cm] ( 1,0) node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt,label=below:$k$](k){};
  \draw (x) -- (y);
  \draw[dotted] (y) -- (z);
  \draw (z) -- (k);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To increase the spacing between the dots, add the following to the `tikzpicture` options:

```
dotted/.style={dash pattern=on \pgflinewidth off 5pt}
```

where `5pt` ist the new spacing.